# Another Limit of a Sequence Question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Use the definition of a limit of a sequence to prove

$\lim_{n\to\infty} b^n = 0$ if $0<b<1$ using the facts that $b = 1/(1+a)$, $a>0$, and Bernoulli's inequality $(1+a)^n \ge na$.

The definition that I am using by the way is letting $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, show that there exists an $N$ that is an element of the Natural numbers such that $n\ge N$ implies $|b^n - 0| < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon\gt 0$, we want to make $|b^n-0|\lt \epsilon$, that is, $b^n\lt \epsilon$.

By the hint, $b^n=\frac{1}{(1+a)^n}\le \frac{1}{na}$. So we will be OK if $\frac{1}{na}\lt \epsilon$, or equivalently if $n \gt \frac{1}{a\epsilon}$. Thus choosing $N$ to be the smallest integer $\gt \frac{1}{\epsilon a}$ will do the job.